# I cannot use npm install in react-native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, react-native, npm

I create react-native-app and want to install redux and navigation but I got this error. So I try to delete node_module in project and re-install node_module but I got same error
In my com have node v.10.13  npm v.6.4.1

in step: expo init   ->  `npm install react-redux redux`  -> get error   -> delete node_module  -> `npm install` -> get same error

this is error

> npm ERR! code ENOGIT
> npm ERR! Error while executing:
> npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/expo/react-native-> maps.git
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! undefined
> npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed using git.
> npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Achirawat Juasawad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-11-21T16_32_33_305Z-debug.log

About GIT, I never install git in my com and it's not have this problem before.

Comment: Did you try installing Git? The messages is saying: `No git binary found in $PATH`

Comment: try with `sudo npm install`

Comment: Oh! it work thank but why it have problem now? this is second project with native. first app doesn't have this error.